# The definition of manifold

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let **$M$** hausdorff topological space , we say **$M$** is $n$- dimensional manifold if each open set **$U$** in **$M$** is homeomorphic to an open set **$E$** in **$R^n$**

My question is

should **$R^n$** be equipped by Euclidean topology that induced by the distance $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ or I can equipp it by discrete topology ?

Comment: $\Bbb R^n$is supposed to be taken (as is in general the case unless specified otherwise) with its standard topology. (And besides one usually adds some countability condition to the definition of manifold)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen you meant I can't take it with discrete topology ?

Comment: If you do that then you would be using the word "manifold" in a different way than everyone else. I am not saying Euclidean space with the discrete topology is completely useless, but why are you interested in doing that?

Comment: @KCd I would like to know what will happen if I change the topology defined on **$R^n$** ?

Comment: What will happen? Essentially nobody will care about such a concept.

Comment: @Neilhawking many things happen. Can you be more specific? For instance, compare the classes of continuous functions in the two different topologies....

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 as you mentioned . The differentiable mappings , the differentiable functions ,  determine whether I can define riemann or pseudo-riemann metric on this "manifold" ?

Comment: @Neilhawking so is your question really "can i define a riemann or pseudo-riemann metric on a space that looks like real $n$-space with the discrete topology?" (Where by "looks like" i mean locally homeomorphic)

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 do you think it is a good idea for master thesis ?

Comment: @Neilhawking That is a question for your advisor or mentor, presuming you are in graduate school. I do not have any experience choosing or overseeing thesis topics and I am currently trying to get into graduate myself. So, by far, I am not qualified at all to give you any advice on this issue. You should look inward and get in touch with your immediate mathematical community.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 thank you so much